# Creating and appending CSV from powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to create a csv file from powershell with the following headers "A,B,C,D"

Under each header, I wish to append data to the csv file after it is created.

I'm currently using

```
$csv = "Path,Publish,Hashlist,Package`r`n"
$fso = new-object -comobject scripting.filesystemobject
$file = $fso.CreateTextFile($path,$true)
$file.write($csv)
$file.close()
```

to create the csv and trying to append it with

```
Add-Content browser.csv "$filepath, $publishtimestamp, $hashdestination, $packagedestination"
```

However, when appending the .csv file I've created here, it doesn't work correctly and looks like an encoding error.  If I manually create the csv with those headers and then append, it works fine.  Any ideas on the correct way to create a csv for my purposes?

Comment: I would highly, highly suggest looking at the Export-CSV cmdlet. You are re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: If I wanted to create the CSV initially with just the headers in the top line, would you be able to explain how to do that with Export-CSV? I'm not too familiar with creating an object for export with only one line of content

Comment: Iguess that I would question the need to do this. It could be done, but it would be a little hacky. Instead why not just let Export-CSV create the headers the first time that you actually write data out?

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing encoding issues, use the `-Encoding` flag of `Out-File` and `Add-Content` to specify the encoding you want (UTF8 etc.) Why are you not using Powershell cmdlets for this? Powershell provides easier ways to write to a file, append to a file etc. Not to mention that there is the `Export-Csv` cmdlet for easily manipulating csv.